# Promise.try without bluebird

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am trying to re-create bluebird's promise.try function, is this essentially the same?

```
function promiseTry(callback) {
  let error;
  let value;
  try {
    value = callback();
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
      throw error;
    }
    resolve(value);
  });
}

const x = promiseTry(() => {
  throw new Error('hi');
});
```

How can I simply implement bluebird's `Promise.try` with a native node Promise?

Comment: FYI, here's the [Bluebird source](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/method.js#L25) for `Promise.try()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```js
function promiseTry(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resolve(callback())
    } catch(e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

const x = promiseTry(() => {
  throw new Error('hi');
});

x.then(() => console.log("Promise resolved")).catch(err => console.log("Promise rejected:", err.message));
```

If you can use `async/await`, `async function`s have this behavior implicitly. Any synchronous exceptions thrown in an async function are converted into a promise rejection.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I think the issue here is that `Promise.try` will throw sync errors.

Comment: @ThomasReggi `Promise.try` converts sync errors into promise rejections. This is also what your sample code does and is what is shown in my code snippet. I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show more clearly that the `throw` is being caught and turned into a promise rejection, exactly how bluebird would.